# Syntastic and jshint not displaying errors in vim

Tags: vim, syntastic

I can't get Syntastic to work for JavaScript files in MacVim. If I save a file with errors in it, nothing is displayed: there is no error margin.

If I run `:SyntasticInfo`, then I see:

```
Syntastic info for filetype: javascript
Available checkers: jshint
Currently active checker(s): jshint
```

If I run `jshint` directly, using `:!jshint %`, then I see the errors I expect.

Answer (score 5):

I had a custom `syntastic_javascript_jshint_conf` setting:

```
let g:syntastic_javascript_jshint_conf="~/.jshintrc"
```

...and the `~/.jshintrc` file was missing. Recreating it fixed the problem, and now I get the error margin.

**Updated to add:** I've added a feature to my `.vimrc`, so that it tracks the "nearest" `.jshintrc` file: https://github.com/rlipscombe/vimrc/blob/master/vimrc#L176